# Boundary of subset of the space of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $T>0$ and $\Omega = (0,1) \times (0,2)$ and consider the set $X = C([0,T];C(\overline \Omega)) \sim C([0,T]\times \overline \Omega)$ which is the set of continuous functions $f: [0,T] \times \overline \Omega \to \mathbb{R}.$ I work in the uniform convergence norm, i.e., $$\|f\| = \sup\limits_{(t,x) \in [0,T] \times \overline \Omega} |f(t,x)|$$

Now, let $r, R \in \mathbb{R}$, $r < R$ and define $$K = \{ f \in X; r \leqslant f(t,x) \leqslant R, \forall (t,x) \in [0,T] \times \overline \Omega\}.$$

I am trying to compute $\partial K.$ I know that $f \equiv r$ and $f \equiv R$ belong to $\partial K$, but they are not the only ones, are they?

Comment: Any $f\in K$ with $f(t,x)=r$ for some $(t,x)$ belongs to $\partial K$ right? Because $f-\delta \notin K$ for any $\delta>0$. Similarly if $f$ has $f(t,x)=R$ for some $(t,x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$U = \{ f \in X; r < f(t,x) < R, \forall (t,x) \in [0,T] \times \overline \Omega\}.$$ Consider any $f\in U$.
Then, since $f$ has a minimum and maximum, we can define
$$
m:=\min\{ f(t,x):t,x\in [0,t]\times\overline\Omega\},
\quad
M:=\max\{ f(t,x):t,x\in [0,t]\times\overline\Omega\}.
$$
We get $r<m\leq M<R$. If $g$ is a function satisfying $\|f-g\|<\rho$, where $\rho=\min\{m-r,R-M\}$ then $g\in U$. This shows that $U$ is open.

Similarly one can prove that $K$ is closed.

This shows that $\partial K\subset K\setminus U$. Let's prove the converse. Consider $f\in K\setminus U$, i.e.
$r \leq f(t,x) \leq R$, for all  $(t,x) \in [0,T] \times \overline \Omega$ but for some $(t,x)$ we get the equality $f(t,x)=R$ or $f(t,x)=r$.

- If $f(t,x)=R$ then the function $f_n(x)=f(x)+\frac 1n$ is very close to $f$ but it doesn't belong to $K$. Therefore $f\in\partial K$.
- If $f(t,x)=r$ then the function $f_n(x)=f(x)-\frac 1n$ is very close to $f$ but it doesn't belong to $K$. Therefore $f\in\partial K$.

We got that $$\partial K = K\setminus U = \{ f \in K; f(t,x)\in\{r,R\}\text{ for some } (t,x) \in [0,T] \times \overline \Omega\}.$$

Comment: thank you very much for the reply. :)